# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: 16.04, mysql

Installed MySQL on Ubuntu Mate 16.04. When I am going to create new DB connection below error message is showing:

```
Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 127.0.0.1:3306:

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Please:
1 Check that mysql is running on server 127.0.0.1
2 Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3 Check the root has rights to connect to 127.0.0.1 from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines) 
4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for 127.0.0.1 connecting from the host address you're connecting from
```

Comment: Is your mysql server running? Check with 'ps -ef | grep sql'. Are you just trying to connect for the first time after installing?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the command you are using to connect to your MySQL server (e.g. `mysql -u root -p`) and also as which user you're trying to execute the command.

Comment: Also please add the output of `service mysql status` as it might indicate what's wrong.